# Does it possible to 'member function pointer' points to a member function in same class

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

### Code

```
class cat{

        public:
           void walk(){
                printf("cat is walking \n");
           }

           void myAbc(){
               void (*pKoo)();
               pKoo = &this->walk;
           }

          void myDef(){
               void(cat::*pFoo)();
               pFoo = &this->walk;
          }
        }

    };
```

### Result

1. void (*pKoo)(); - No problem
2. pKoo = &this->walk; - Compiling error
3. void(cat::*pFoo)(); - No problem
4. pFoo = &this->walk; - compile error;

### Question

- Why no 2 impossible? If Impossible, Then what is the use of No 1?
- Why no 4 impossible? If Impossible, Then what is the use of No 3?

Please help for conceptual explanation. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why no 2 impossible?

My compiler gives an error message:

```
cannot convert ‘void (cat::*)()’ to ‘void (*)()’ in assignment
```

meaning that you can't convert a pointer-to-member-function to a pointer-to-function. They are incompatible types; a pointer-to-function can be called directly, while a pointer-to-member-function needs to be applied to an object. So the type you assign to has to be pointer-to-member-function, or `void (cat::*)();`, as you correctly use in 3.

> If Impossible, Then what is the use of No 1?

It's used to store a pointer to a static or non-member function.

> Why no 3 impossible?

(I assume you mean 4, not 3.) My compiler gives an error message:

```
ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to form a 
pointer to member function.  Say ‘&cat::walk’
```

For some reason, you're not allowed to take the address of a member function using an object (or pointer); you have to use the class name instead. We can only speculate on why this isn't allowed; perhaps because it's not entirely clear which override should be chosen if it's virtual, or perhaps for some other reason.

Whatever the reason, use the allowed syntax: `pFoo = &cat::walk;`

Comment: Hi Mike, got some idea and thank you. And if I append the main function like here.  `int main(){` `cat bigCat;` `void (cat::*pcat)();` `pcat = &cat::walk;` `bigCat.*pcat();` . Why this is impossible?

Comment: for more clear

`class cat{

        public:
           void walk(){
                printf("cat is walking \n");
           }
}


int main(){
 cat bigCat;
 void (cat::*pcat)();
 pcat = &cat::walk;
 bigCat.*pcat();
}`

Comment: You're missing some parentheses. To bind and call the member function pointer, you want `(bigCat.*pcat)()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void (*pKoo)();                
pKoo = &this->walk;
```

gives you error because the function pointer type does not match with the type of the function whose address you are assigning to it.

The type of `walk()` is:

```
void (cat::*)(void);
```

---

```
void(cat::*pFoo)();
pKoo = &this->walk;
```

should be:

```
pKoo = &cat::walk;
```

The method `walk` belongs to the class `cat` and not to any particular instance of the class. Hence you cannot use `this->walk()` but you need to qualify the method name with the class name.

Comment: Also you should use &cat::walk instead of &this->walk.

Comment: So when the program runs. what is the actual function pointer assign to "pKoo". as Ex. if I create a instance from this class and call "myAbc",

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya: That question makes no sense; you can't call `myAbc` because it won't compile. If you change it to assign a pointer to a static or non-member function to `pKoo`, then `pKoo` will point to that function.